# Disk usage at 100% during startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, disk-activity

Every time I start my computer, I have to wait 15 - 20 minutes just for it to actually be usable because disk usage is stuck at 100% and causing high lag. I have no idea why, and I tried a few solutions like disabling Windows search.

The running processes also don't add up to 100%, sometimes the highest running usage is only around 16% but it still shows a total of 100%. Usually, system is the highest one though.

If it helps, I am on Windows 10 and have an HDD disk, computer was made in 2015.

Comment: The problem is a slow HDD. Windows has only gotten larger and has a big footprint meaning long load times. I would recommend replacing the HDD with an SSD.

Comment: Have you checkef your hdd's SMART values? Sounds like a failing disk to me.

Comment: Most definitely the HDD. Try getting an SSD if that's possible, but considering your computer is old by now this might not solve it satisfactorily, in which case I'd go for a new one.

Comment: There was a similar issue on old Intel CPUs when IRST software was installed. What's your CPU?

Comment: How often do you use the computer in question? Background tasks on modern Windows systems can cause serious problems for HDD users, the worst offender I've seen is Windows Update, it can keep *seeking* your disk for half an hour to run updates. If the machine is only used occasionally, it means it's self-updating every time when you need it...

Comment: My Windows 7 PC is from 2009, and it still works very well. It's just as fast as it was when I first bought it. (And I am spending many hours each day working with it: writing documents, programming, editing videos, running simulations etc.) But I also suffer from problems like this one. If I need to restart the machine, I have to wait half an hour or more before I can actually use it. So I'm quite happy that I don't receive many updates any more, and I have impressive uptimes.

Comment: Seconding all the 'get an ssd' replies, but also I've seen this behavior when windows updates never get to finish, especially if it's not left on much and the malware scan and the update scan are competing for harddrive time. I've fixed it for people by spending an entire day running windows update, rebooting, and then doing the whole thing over again until it was 100% updated. Doing the disk cleanup to reduce the amount of files the malware scan hits also seems to help.

Comment: Don't get an SSD yet. I have encountered this issue on my pc and this problem seems specific to windows. I have since then switched to Linux - boot time was reduced by a factor more than 3 and programs open much quicker than in windows. Likely a combination of no anti-malware, less bloat and telemetry. When you do upgrade you pc in the future, it would likely come with an SSD, and no additional slots to expand, so I'd advice against buying an SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk usage is always at 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/1044707/disk-usage-is-always-at-100)

Answer (score 24):

First, 15 minutes startup is ludicrous, even with HDD. Some suggestions:

1. In *Task Manager* on the *Details* tab, or using Sysinternal's [*Process Explorer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (below), click on the column header and add columns, particularly for

   - Priority
   - I/O Reads
   - I/O Writes

[image: Process Explorer: finding usage hogs]

2. Run *Task Manager* or  *Process Manager* during startup -- you could even add it to a *Startup* folder. Note the I/O usage hogs.

   - [csrss.exe, *Client Server Runtime Subsystem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem) would certainly be one, but it is a fundamental part of Windows and must be endured *as is*.
   - [MsMpEng.exe](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/what-is-msmpeng-exe-and-should-you-remove-it) is part of Windows Security, and *at startup*, it scans certain files. Though it is *possible* to run without a malware suite, it is **highly inadvisable for Windows OS!** Likely, any other free or commercial anti-malware suite will also cause the same issue. In the link above, you can find hints to reduce the frequency of scans. [If you want to run an OS that does *not* require such an anti-malware suite, consider Linux. On the PC I am now using, with HDD, Windows takes about seven minutes to boot and finish initial scanning for malware; Ubuntu about two minutes.]
   - Look for any other I/O "hogs". You should **not** have another anti-malware suite running in parallel with Windows Defender! Occasional scans by a stand-alone tool, such [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/solutions/virus-scanner), can provide reassurance, though.
   - It is possible to set an obnoxious high-priority process to a lower setting at startup. For example, the short script below, in a .bat file, decreases priority for *StartMenu* and *StartMenuExperienceHost* with no ill effect on my PC's (though I use the third-party [Open-Shell](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/) to customize the *Start Menu,* so have little need for the MS version).

> wmic process where name="StartMenu.exe" CALL setpriority 64

> wmic process where name="StartMenuExperienceHost.exe" CALL setpriority 64

3. Some other things to speed up *Startup*:

   - In *Task Manager*, on the *Startup* tab, check *Startup impact*, and disable unneeded apps.
   - Perform all Windows updates, then use [SFC and DISM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) to repair any issues.
   - Rather than perform a full shutdown, *Hibernate*, which uses *no power*, or *Sleep*, *if* the PC is left plugged in. Return from *Hibernate* may take half as long as rebooting, and resumption from *Sleep* just seconds.
4. As for replacing the HDD with an SSD, it might or *might not* be worth the trouble. You would need to transfer at least the OS to SSD, likely need to reinstall some applications, and you'd still have an eight-year-old PC. As mentioned above, I've found Linux, such as Ubuntu, far leaner than Windows, yet all my frequently used apps are there: Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice and others. If you want to try Linux, no need to install to test it: just run from a [Live Ubuntu USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started), which likely would boot faster than from the HDD running Windows.

Comment: As to MsMpEng.exe, I found this guide with a lot of screenshots helpful: [What is msmpeng.exe? Why is it High CPU Disk Usage?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-msmpeng-exe-why-is-it-of-high-cpu-disk-usage/). Disabling the check of its own folder made some changes, the disk is still too noisy, but right after adding that folder to the exclusions, I often find short drops to 90 % and sometimes even to only 30 % disk usage and less, then going up to 100% again, and that, while Windows updates are running. Before the exclusion of the folder, it was always at 100 %

Comment: I have restarted my dinosaur again and must find that the change for MSMpEng.exe (to take out its own folder) does not help. My computer still lags heavily for at least half an hour. Therefore, I guess that from this answer, you know the why, and that there is no fix in the end, and even though 3.) works for me, it also takes half an hour. Thus 4.) is the only answer, you just need an SSD where even the worst is 30 times faster than the fastest HDD, I did not know that it was so much faster: they can have 7,000 MBps for reads and 5,000 MBps for writes while HDDs reach at the most 160 MBps.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like it is the HDD.  When it starts getting errors it spends a lot of time retrying to read the bad sectors.  SO, take this as an early warning sign to save your data by replacing it with another SSD.

If you look at the event log, search for Event IDs

> The following Event IDs indicate that there's data corruption or a disk error:
>
> - Event ID 153
>
>   The IO operation at logical block address 123456 for Disk 2 was retried.
> - Event ID 129
>
>   Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort1, was issued.
> - Event ID 55
>
>   The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume.
> - Event ID 98
>
>   Volume C: (\Device\HarddiskVolume3) needs to be taken offline to perform a Full Chkdsk. Please run "CHKDSK /F" locally via the command line or run "REPAIR-VOLUME drive:" locally or remotely via PowerShell.

From [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/troubleshoot-data-corruption-and-disk-errors)

And run chkdsk

- Open Command Prompt
- type in `chkdsk c: /scan`

  This is read-only.  If there are many errors then it's best to switch your disk.  If you are feeling brave you can try fixing them
- type in `chkdsk C: /f`

  This will try to repair it.

Comment: If the disk is failing, running chkdsk may cause more damage, even in read-only mode.

Comment: This is most likely the answer. High chance the disk is dying and needs to be replaced urgently. The 15-20 minutes of high disk activity is also quite likely caused by bad blocks, and then Windows running chkdsk in the background... every time it boots. Although I do agree - chkdsk can often make the damage worse. OP needs to not mess around and get all data fully backed up asap if not already: and don't overwrite existing backups in case the current data is corrupt and the original backup was actually fine.

Comment: The only suggestion I'd make is removing "HDD or" from this. It's 2023, SSDs are cheaper, faster, and generally more reliable for standard use than spinning disks

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I don't know where you shop, but SSDs are definitely NOT cheaper than HDDs.

Comment: Amazon... If you ignore the sale price anyway https://www.amazon.co.uk/Seagate-BarraCuda-Internal-Drive-Cache/dp/B07H28QRKN/ref=sr_1_3?crid=QZMNPS4VKJCN&keywords=1tb+hdd+2.5%22&qid=1676989851&sprefix=1tb+hdd+2.5+%2Caps%2C194&sr=8-3 https://www.amazon.co.uk/Patriot-P220-Internal-Solid-State/dp/B0BS9Z2FFT/ref=sr_1_15?crid=3A6GDOV0NSNG5&keywords=1tb+ssd&qid=1676989858&sprefix=1tb+ss%2Caps%2C180&sr=8-15

Answer (score 10):

I'd say it's definitely the HDD who has now problems - of course, worsen by the 10 yrs old PC (motherboard, CPU...)

Do NOT hesitate. For maybe 40$ or even less - depending where you are - you can acquire an SSD for your system.

ANY brand will be FAR FAR faster than your HDD. Don't hesitate to take less reputed brands. Of course, if on Amazon have a look at the ratings ;-)

Even on old systems you can boot completely in like 15 seconds with an SSD.

I'd recommend you to download the free DiskGenius:

https://www.diskgenius.com/

Because it's free, works perfectly for this, and can make a live copy / migration of your system.

- Install the new SSD.
- Use OS Migration icon/menu option, and follow the guide to migrate to the SSD.
- Select the Hot live copy (using system snapshot).
- When done, simply turn off the PC, unplug the SATA of the old HDD and restart.

It should boot now on the SSD.

*In case of any problem - but there shouldn't be any - simply unplug the new SSD and plug back the HDD.*

Comment: Being far far faster is no help if it's far less reliable.  Reliability is what should drive product selection, not performance.  (In case it is not clear, I am emphatically disagreeing with your suggestion not to worry about brand)

Comment: True - but are also steps you can climb progressively. And there has been many problems with Samsung EVO 870 and IIRC 840... while my poor (almost) Nonames last for years - so quality is complicated...

Comment: Since it is quite likely that for most of us the MsMpEng.exe Windows Defender service leads to this problem, and since that is a Windows service that should not be stopped, it might be good to have a faster SSD, they can have 7,000 MBps for reads and 5,000 MBps for writes while HDDs reach perhaps 160 MBps, see [SSD vs HDD: Which is best and how are they different?](https://www.tomsguide.com/reference/ssd-vs-hdd-which-is-best-and-how-are-they-different).

Answer (score 3):

Disable the SysMain service (search for "Services").

I think this used to be called Prefetch or Superfetch.
My boot time dropped from 10 minutes to 3 minutes.
I too have just an HDD (and agree with everyone else
that an SSD would be much faster) and assume that
chkdsk shows that your HDD is fine.

(Windows Update sometimes still hogs my disk, but I have
given up on understanding that even though menus make
me think that I can disable it temporarily.)

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me constantly, and I agree it's aggravating. The way I normally investigate this is to launch Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Escape), go to the "Details" tab, and add the column named "PF Delta".  This will tell you how many times a program tried to access something that wasn't in memory and had to go out to the hard drive to get it (a [*page fault*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)).  I find this works better if you select View -> Update Speed -> Slow.  I usually see a small handful of programs that are throwing huge numbers of page faults and the rest are close to zero.  Those few programs are what are hammering your hard drive and bringing the system to a crawl.  Some programs might appear under a generic name, but adding the "Command Line" column can provide more details as to what exactly is running.

Also, the "Startup" tab in Task Manager will show you what all is running at startup and how big of an impact it has on your startup time.

99% of the time, the culprit is something that's trying to auto-update itself.  Update routines rarely throttle themselves, run invisibly in the background, and generate a lot of disk traffic.  If your system ends up with two or more update routines running at the same time, the resulting traffic can cause hard drive thrashing (where the drive spends all its time seeking back and forth and very little doing data transfer).

Take a look at your system the next time this happens and see if you have several update tasks running.  Windows Update is normally one of the culprits (`wuauserv` service).  The Edge browser is frequently another culprit that I see, as are security/antivirus programs.

You can alleviate this somewhat by scheduling programs to update themselves at different times.  You can completely [disable Edge browser updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698285/disable-auto-update-on-edge-browser-installed-on-windows-server-2019) if you don't use it. If you *do* use that browser, you can reconfigure the "Microsoft Edge Update Service" and change its "Startup Type" from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Delayed Start)".  This will wait a little bit before starting the update process.  The default is around 2 minutes, but you can change this by [setting a registry key](https://web.archive.org/web/20160205094320/http://www.ca.com/us/support/ca-support-online/product-content/knowledgebase-articles/tec1854551.aspx) `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<service name>\AutoStartDelay` to a time delay in seconds.  This should work for any auto-updater that runs as a service.  I use this to ensure that Windows updates, Edge updates, my antivirus auto-update, etc. run at different times by giving them ~10 minute delays relative to each other.  That lets one process run and finish before the next one starts, preventing them from thrashing the hard drive and monopolizing the entire machine.  Once I did that I saw a noticable difference in performance when the system initially starts up.

Comment: "PF Delta" = "Page Fault Delta" = German: "Veränderung der Seitenfehler", see [What is Performance Monitor telling me when my page faults / second are high?](https://superuser.com/q/240578/1192848) for more.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem several times and it was always caused by Windows telemetry (see also [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-compattelrunnerexe-on-win10-64-bit-and-why/3af9a0ea-bb18-4df7-99d5-4930ae59d247)).

After start, open *Task Manager*, click on *Details* and see whether there is any `CompatTelRunner.exe` process running. There should be 2 (sometimes 3) instances. Kill them all (actually, killing one usually ends the other one too if you pick the right one).

If HDD stops spinning like crazy, you know this is the cause.

To disable telemetry, do the following: *Task Scheduler > Microsoft > Windows > Application Experience > right click on each task to disable it* as [described here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stop-the-windows-compatability-telemetry/3e6f469a-e527-4744-a313-cb52030b3461).

Note 1: my experience is that telemetry always comes back, so you might need to repeat this in the future. Or just keep killing it after the startup.

Note 2: such telemetry scans not only happen after system starts, but also e.g. after you install/uninstall a program.

Note 3: as others suggested, a lot of things happen after the start (prefetch, AV scan, ...). Telemetry might not be the only reason for your problems. But from my experience, it has the biggest impact.

Final advice: if possible, switch to SSD. It will improve (not only) the startup speed immensely.

Comment: Agree that telemetry is a pain. But OP talks about a 20 MINUTES long boot up to usable Windows. I can't believe telemetry is a the problem here. But again, yes, it's a pain I think I also disabled it...

Comment: @Sylvain it was cca 15 min on my old PC. I kid you not. I guess it also depends on how many files are on the disk. I have a lot of VMs in the work and not all are on SSD. It takes less time on them, that's true. Still, it's usually several minutes unless I kill CompatTelRunner. I do not understand how MS folks do not experience this during their testing. I guess they only have SSDs now ;-)