# Expand C drive to another empty disk?

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory, disk-space, disk-management

[image: Disk Management]

Can I convert my disks to dynamic. Then add the free unallocated space from disk 0 to extend C drive volume?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend a disk partition to another disk. That cannot be done.

You can add a D: drive as another drive. It can be basic or dynamic, but I always use Basic.

If you need a bigger drive, then it appears now is the time to get a larger drive for your computer.

It is better (best in my view) to keep Windows on Drive C. Windows mean Windows files and folders, Program Files, Program Data and USER folders on Drive C:

Then if necessary put Documents on drive D.  Use Document Properties to do this.  Screen shot attached.

A large drive is best.

[image: Relocate Documents]

Comment: @John, can you please clarify a bit; what do you mean moving Documents on D "only if necessary"? When would it be more appropriate to keep data on system drive if they can be separated?

Comment: The Document folder Properties allow changing to a different drive.  Answer clarified

Comment: I still don't comprehend. I'd say "It is better (best in my view) to keep Windows on Drive C and put Documents on drive D". What's the only if necessary meaning?

Comment: @Sylvain It means it's optional.

Comment: I clarified what I mean by Windows to help everyone

Comment: I edited my reply. And I'd say "ALWAYS put Documents folder on another drive - unless of course you never use those system folders" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible for the System drive.

Even if, I wouldn't do it, as using 2 disks you multiply by 2 the chances your system is locked if one of the drive fails; and it'll fail one day.

You've got a 120GB SSD I guess, great - but a 240 or 480GB is nowadays cheap.

If you can afford it, use this procedure describe [here](https://superuser.com/a/1769462/1773228), for ex.

Edited after comments below.

I'd add you could **both** save room in C: and have a **far more safer PC** while separating system and data.

The idea is to leave your C: drive with the minimum, the system and the applications.

Everything else could be in another drive (or another *primary* partition, but another drive is even better) - like D: or E:

This way, in case of any system failure or reinstall/upgrade needed, you can easily do about everything on your C: drive, but your personal data, your documents and pictures, are safe on another drive (that you can unplug during the transition).

You can easily transfer your usual "Documents", "Pictures", "Music" etc folders to another place than C: where they're located by default: right-click, Properties, Location, Move => to D: for example.